# What is supposed to be used as $m$ in $m\lambda = d\sin \theta $

Tags: experimental-physics, hydrogen, photon-emission

I know that $m$ is the "order number", but I don't understand how this applies to the lab we did. We looked at Hydrogen gas through a diffraction grating (500 lines/cm or something like that) and saw that certain colors were noticeably bright. We measured the distance from a spectrum line to the center/towards the gas. We then used this to find theta. Now I need to use the equation in the title of this question to find lambda, but I'm not sure what to use for $m$.

Comment: An integer number, where m=0 corresponds to the transmitted light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When light passes through a diffraction grating, it gets diffracted at many different angles. Something like [this](http://h2physics.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/colorgrating.jpg) image happens. The smallest diffraction angles correspond to $m=1$, the next angle corresponds to $m=2$, etc. I'd imagine in your lab you measured the FIRST spectrum line, so that means $m=1$.

As a side note, $m=1$ corresponds to a phase difference of $2\pi$, $m=2$ corresponds to a phase difference of $4\pi$, and in general $m$ corresponds to a phase difference of $2m\pi$. I don't know if you've discussed that at your level of physics, but I just thought I'd throw it in for completeness.